# Sort "get_pages" by menu order not ordering

Tags: get-posts, pages

I'm using this bit of code to generate a page full of items but they won't sort into the menu order, any ideas as to why?

```
   <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of', 'menu_order')); ?>
```

Comment: Why did you create $arg for arguments and didn't use it?

Comment: That makes no sense, check the codex for the right syntax! http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should look like this:

`<?php
        $pages = get_pages( array('sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
?>`